# Flutter ChangeNotifierProvider the parameter 'update' is required

Tags: flutter, dart

with the latest updates I got this:

> warning: The parameter 'update' is required. . (missing_required_param
>   at [pos_mobile] lib\main.dart)

```
 return MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
            value: Auth(),
          ),
          ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Operatori>( // here I got the warning
            builder: (ctx, auth, prevData) => Operatori(auth.token, auth.userId,
                prevData == null ? [] : prevData.operatori),
          ),
```

thanks

Comment: where is the 38th line?

Comment: is just a part of the code,i put a comment where I got the warning

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check the ChangeNotifierProxyProvider [doc](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProxyProvider-class.html)

It should be :

```
ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Foo, MyChangeNotifier>(
  create: (_) => MyChangeNotifier(),
  update: (_, foo, myNotifier) => myNotifier
    ..foo = foo,
  child: ...
);
```

Comment: tried this but not working,my provider needs 3 parameters,create gives one: ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Operatori>(
             create: (_) =>  Operatori(auth.token, auth.userId),
          ....

Comment: @mrapi then you can refractor your notifier to use the syntax as shown here

Comment: ok,I've removed the constructor and used setters,changed my code like this:  ChangeNotifierProxyProvider<Auth, Operatori>(
            create: (_) => Operatori(),
            update: (_, auth, myNotifier){ myNotifier..authToken=auth.token;myNotifier..userId= auth.userId;},
          ),    but now got:  This function has a return type of 'Operatori', but doesn't end with a return statement.
Try adding a return statement, or changing the return type to 'void'.

Comment: @mrapi The update parameter need to return the notifier, but there isnt any in yours. In your code, return myNotifier in update section

Comment: I have 2 values,it should be:   update: (_, auth, myNotifier)=>myNotifier..authToken=auth.token..userId= auth.userId,      ?

Comment: You can do anything w your logical business. But it must return a notifier there :).

update: (_, auth, myNotifier) { authToken=auth.token; userId= auth.userId; return myNotifier }.

Comment: how to can we use `notifyListeners()` in the update function of model. I tried it is giving the error `setstate() or markneedsbuild() called during build`. The error comes when I hot reload.